# Sort column by date in my excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, date

I have a macro that will search my sales data from multiple worksheets for a specific item and then display the all sales by that item into a different worksheet. It works perfectly but now i want it to sort the date column (column A)

What do i need to add to this code to have it sort by date (newest to oldest)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!
Steve

```
Option Compare Text

Sub finddata()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim datasheet1 As Worksheet
Dim datasheet2 As Worksheet
Dim datasheet3 As Worksheet
Dim datasheet4 As Worksheet
Dim datasheet5 As Worksheet
Dim datasheet6 As Worksheet
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
Dim itemname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Set datasheet1 = Sheet6
Set datasheet2 = Sheet5
Set datasheet3 = Sheet4
Set datasheet4 = Sheet3
Set datasheet5 = Sheet2
Set datasheet6 = Sheet1
Set reportsheet = Sheet7
itemname = reportsheet.Range("B2").Value

datasheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
datasheet3.Visible = xlSheetVisible
datasheet4.Visible = xlSheetVisible
datasheet5.Visible = xlSheetVisible
datasheet6.Visible = xlSheetVisible

reportsheet.Range("A5:N100").ClearContents

datasheet1.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = itemname Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 14)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet1.Select
    End If
Next i

datasheet2.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(j, 2) = itemname Then
    Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 14)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet2.Select
    End If
Next j

datasheet3.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For k = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(k, 2) = itemname Then
    Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k, 14)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet3.Select
    End If
Next k

datasheet4.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For l = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(l, 2) = itemname Then
    Range(Cells(l, 1), Cells(l, 14)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet4.Select
    End If
Next l

datasheet5.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For m = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(m, 2) = itemname Then
    Range(Cells(m, 1), Cells(m, 14)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet5.Select
    End If
Next m

datasheet6.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For n = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(n, 2) = itemname Then
    Range(Cells(n, 1), Cells(n, 14)).Copy
    reportsheet.Select
    Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    datasheet6.Select
    End If
Next n

datasheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
datasheet3.Visible = xlSheetHidden
datasheet4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
datasheet5.Visible = xlSheetHidden
datasheet6.Visible = xlSheetHidden

reportsheet.Select

Range("H2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort column A using the code below. You will need to replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name.

```
Sub SortColA()
'
' Sort column A newest to oldest
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:A")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How would i insert that into my current code? when i did that and replaced "Sheet1" with "reportsheet" it gave me errors

Comment: What error code and description did you get? I might be able to find out what went wrong.?

Comment: I am getting a subscript out of range error on the second line of your code. I have changed "Sheet1" to "reportsheet" in your code. I even tried "Sheet7" which is the sheet i want sorted and its the same error. My code has reportsheet = sheet7 so both should work